# Count duplicate dates occurrences

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I've a collection in MongoDB of objects with this structure:

```
  {
    "_id": "ID",
    "email": "EMAIL",
    "name": "Foo",
    "surname": "Bar",
    "orders": [
      {
        "createdAt": "2019-09-09T07:30:25.575Z"
      },
      {
        "createdAt": "2019-10-30T14:20:04.849Z"
      },
      {
        "createdAt": "2019-10-30T16:38:27.271Z"
      },
      {
        "createdAt": "2020-01-03T15:49:39.614Z"
      },
    ],
  }
```

I need to count all duplicates "createdAt" and distinct it with changing date format.
The result should be like below:

```
{
    "_id": "ID",
    "email": "EMAIL",
    "name": "Foo",
    "surname": "Bar",
    "orders": [
      {
        "date": "2019-09-09",
        "total": 1,
      },
      {
        "date": "2019-10-30",
         "total": 2,
      },
      {
        "date": "2020-01-03",
        "total": 1,
      },
    ],
  }
```

I tried with `$unwind` ***orders.createdAt*** in `db.collection.aggregate()` but i've no idea how can i get this result.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are those `createdAt` fields real ISO8601 strings or mongoDB datetimes that are being pretty-printed as IS8601 strings?

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti mongoDB datetimes format in ISO8601

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on for size.  Given this data:

```
db.foo.insert([
{
    "_id": "ID",
        "email": "EMAIL", "name": "Foo", "surname": "Bar",
        "orders": [
                   { "createdAt": new Date("2019-09-09T07:30:25.575Z")  },
                   { "createdAt": new Date("2019-10-30T14:20:04.849Z") },
                   { "createdAt": new Date("2019-10-30T16:38:27.271Z") },
                   { "createdAt": new Date("2020-01-03T15:49:39.614Z") }
                   ]
        },
{
    "_id": "ID2",
        "email": "EMAIL2", "name": "Bin", "surname": "Baz",
        "orders": [
                   { "createdAt": new Date("2019-09-09T07:30:25.575Z")  },
                   { "createdAt": new Date("2020-10-30T14:20:04.849Z") },
                   { "createdAt": new Date("2020-10-30T16:38:27.271Z") },
                   { "createdAt": new Date("2020-10-30T15:49:39.614Z") }
                   ]
}
               ]);
```

This agg:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
{$unwind: "$orders"}

// First $group is on just the Y-M-D part of the date plus the id.  
// This will produce the basic info the OP seeks -- but not in the desired
// data structure:
,{$group: {
        _id: {orig_id: "$_id", d: {$dateToString: {date: "$orders.createdAt", format: "%Y-%m-%d"}} },
        n:{$sum:1} ,
        email: {$first: "$email"},
        name: {$first: "$name"},
        surname: {$first: "$surname"}
    }}

//  The group is not guaranteed to preserve the order of the dates.  So now that
//  the basic agg is done, reorder by DATE.  _id.d is a Y-M-D string but fortunately
//  that sorts correctly for our purposes:
,{$sort: {"_id.d":1}}

//  ...so in the second $group, we pluck just the id from the id+YMD_date key and
//  take the YMD_date+n and *push* it onto a new orders array to arrive at the
//  desired data structure.  We are not guaranteed the order of orig_id (e.g.
//  ID or ID2) but for each id, the push *will* happen in the order of arrival -- which was 
//  sorted correctly in the prior stage!   As an experiment, try changing the 
//  sort to -1 (reverse) and see what happens.
,{$group: {_id: "$_id.orig_id",
           email: {$first: "$email"},
           name: {$first: "$name"},
           surname: {$first: "$surname"},
           orders: {$push: {date: "$_id.d", total: "$n"}} }}

                      ]);
```

yields this output:

```
{
    "_id" : "ID",
    "email" : "EMAIL",
    "name" : "Foo",
    "surname" : "Bar",
    "orders" : [
        {
            "date" : "2019-09-09",
            "total" : 1
        },
        {
            "date" : "2019-10-30",
            "total" : 2
        },
        {
            "date" : "2020-01-03",
            "total" : 1
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "ID2",
    "email" : "EMAIL2",
    "name" : "Bin",
    "surname" : "Baz",
    "orders" : [
        {
            "date" : "2019-09-09",
            "total" : 1
        },
        {
            "date" : "2020-10-30",
            "total" : 3
        }
    ]
}
```

If you are willing to have a slightly more complex return structure and some dupe data in return for greater dynamic behavior by not having to enumerate each field (e.g. `field: {$first: "$field"}` then you can do this:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
{$unwind: "$orders"}

,{$group: {
        _id: {orig_id: "$_id", d: {$dateToString: {date: "$orders.createdAt", format: "%Y-%m-%d"}} },
        n:{$sum:1} ,
        ALL: {$first: "$$CURRENT"}
    }}

,{$group: {_id: "$_id.orig_id",
           ALL: {$first: "$ALL"},
           orders: {$push: {date: "$_id.d", total: "$n"}} }}
                      ]);
```

to yield this:

```
{
    "_id" : "ID2",
    "ALL" : {
        "_id" : "ID2",
        "email" : "EMAIL2",
        "name" : "Bin",
        "surname" : "Baz",
        "orders" : {
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-09-09T07:30:25.575Z")
        }
    },
    "orders" : [
        {
            "date" : "2019-09-09",
            "total" : 1
        },
        {
            "date" : "2020-10-30",
            "total" : 3
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "ID",
    "ALL" : {
        "_id" : "ID",
        "email" : "EMAIL",
        "name" : "Foo",
        "surname" : "Bar",
        "orders" : {
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-10-30T14:20:04.849Z")
        }
    },
    "orders" : [
        {
            "date" : "2019-10-30",
            "total" : 2
        },
        {
            "date" : "2020-01-03",
            "total" : 1
        },
        {
            "date" : "2019-09-09",
            "total" : 1
        }
    ]
}
```